# Why is my server not working after I changed the A records for a second website hosted on it?

Tags: apache, server

I am a beginner at using servers so please excuse me if this is an obvious mistake!

I am running ubuntu on my server, using apache to host my websites. My first website has been hosted successfully for a couple days, which was my first attempt at doing this. There is a second domain I wanted to host on the website, so I did the same thing I did with the first: create a .conf file in sites-available, used a2ensite so that it was present in sites-enabled, created a directory for this website in var/www/html. Everything was fine at first, but I was getting the apache standard entry page instead of my own index.html, so I went back to my domain website and changed the A records, realising that I had put the last 2 numbers in incorrectly.

Immediately after I changed this, weird stuff started happening. I had been connected to the server via SSH, and the server stopped responding to anything I was writing in the shell immediately. I then checked the websites were up, and they weren't showing up when I looked at them from the browser on my laptop, but, for some reason, both websites were (and are still, currently) working fine when I access the websites from a mobile phone.

I repeatedly tried to SSH on, and then tried to ping the server ip, with no response. I then went to the terminal and checked the status of the server, which said everything was fine. I then checked the logs of the ips that had tried to access the websites, and only the mobile phones were showing up.

I shutdown the server then turned it on again. Nothing changed, so I spent the next hour looking through the server from the terminal, looking for anything that had changed so that I could get it to respond to my laptop. I turned off and restarted both apache and ssh, to no avail, then turned off apache hoping, at the very least, to find a way to ssh onto the machine, or get it to respond to a ping.

I then changed the ip back on the domain website, just hoping to reverse back to previous conditions. I used a2dissite on the second website .conf file in sites-enabled. Nothing had any effect, and I still cannot even get the server to even respond to a ping. The websites are, still, operational when accessed from a mobile phone or from the browser on the server, but do not respond and simply time out when you attempt to access them from a laptop or other computer.

I am very confused, and would greatly appreciate any assistance with this. Beginner-language please, this is my first foray into website hosting.